# How to transpose half of the dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe

| cycle_end_date | mid_cycle | Total | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15th Sept | 230 | 600 | 100 | 200 | 50 | 10 |

I want to transpose this dataframe such as:

| cycle_end_date | mid_cycle | Total | Delay | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15th Sept | 230 | 600 | 0 | 100 |
| 15th Sept | 230 | 600 | 1 | 200 |
| 15th Sept | 230 | 600 | 2 | 50 |
| 15th Sept | 230 | 600 | 3 | 10 |

Basically, the columns day0 , day1, day2 will become rows which will come under `mid_cycle` and `total_amt, pending_amt` will get distributed accordingly.
How do we achieve this? `.transpose()` is not giving me the desired results.

Comment: some rows have 4 elements, others 5; kindly fix

Comment: still not fixed; the days in the source df have five elements

Comment: your second example dataframe is not a valid dataframe either.

Comment: hey @sammywemmy I have changed my example. Can you please look at it?

Comment: @Chris hey can you please have a look at it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt`:

```
out =  df.melt(id_vars=['cycle_end_date', 'mid_cycle', 'Total'], 
               var_name='Delay', value_name='new_col')
print(out)


# Output
  cycle_end_date  mid_cycle  Total Delay  new_col
0      15th Sept        230    600     0      100
1      15th Sept        230    600     1      200
2      15th Sept        230    600     2       50
3      15th Sept        230    600     3       10
```

Comment: Thank you! this works! Have upvoted your answer.